# Command line in Visual Studio - how to close popup window?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, command-line, devenv

I have situation like below.
I'm running some command and then I get a popup with Y/N answer. Is there a possibility to force answer Yes and automatically close the window through command line?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `click` a button in an external window, you'll need to hook the window with the button exposed.  You can accomplish this by grabbing the window handle via [FindWindow](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.FindWindow), finding the child button, and sending a BM_CLICK with an API call via [SendMessage](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll/SendMessage.html).

Answer (score 0):

you mean a command window within VS ? I don't think there's anything generic, you could run all sorts of things, depends on what your command is - and how much control over it you have - maybe some example of what you're trying to do could help. 'picking' the window will work but depends again on what you're doing, how custom it is etc.

Comment: Window with message appears after I run a command within command window.